# JS timeout not firing

Tags: javascript, timer

Just can't seem to figure this out, how to prevent the outer loop continuing until the inner loop has executed using setTimeout:

```
    function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }
    var i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++){
        $('t'+i).className = 'show';
        cl('t'+i);
        for (var j=0; j<50; j++){
            cl('b'+i+'='+j+'%');
            setTimeout(function(){ $('b'+i).style.width = j+'%';},200);
        }
    }
```

This little bit of code is supposed to first make elements t0 visible, and then set the width of another element b0 in 1% steps with a time interval of 200ms, and then continue with t1,b1, t2,b2 etc etc.

But there's no 200ms delay, the whole code executes immediately.

--- EDIT ---

I have not explained very well, here's what I want to do:

```
1. show element Ax
2. increase element Bx width by 1% every 200ms until 50%
3. wait until element Bx reaches 50% before continuing
4. increment x
5. goto 1
```

Comment: You do realize that 200 ms is less then one second? So who's to say the delay isn't there? Remember: 1000ms = 1 second

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I know that, I am outputting to the debug console and also I should see the width of the bar increase from 0 to 50% in 200 ms steps which should take 10 seconds, but it's all over in a few miliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

- The timeout functions see the wrong `i` and `j` values
- They all run at the same time (200ms later)

#### The timeout functions see the wrong `i` and `j` values

The main problem is that the function you're passing into `setTimeout` has an enduring reference to the `i` and `j` variables, **not** copies of them as of when the function was created. That means all of the functions will see the value of `i` and `j` as of when they run, which will be `6` and `50` respectively. This is called "closing over" those variables (and the function is called a "closure").

The usual way to fix this is to create the functions in a way that they close over something that doesn't change. There are a couple of ways to do that; my favorite is to use a factory function:

```
function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    $('t'+i).className = 'show';
    cl('t'+i);
    for (var j=0; j<50; j++){
        cl('b'+i+'='+j+'%');
        setTimeout(makeHandler(i, j), 200);
    }
}
function makeHandler(ivalue, jvalue) {
    return function(){ $('b'+ivalue).style.width = jvalue+'%';};
}
```

Now we *call* `makeHandler`, and it returnns us a function that closes over `ivalue` and `jvalue`, which won't change. Or a refinement of the above which lets us dispose of the maker function when we're done with it:

```
function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }
var i = 0;
var makeHandler = function(ivalue, jvalue) {
    return function(){ $('b'+ivalue).style.width = jvalue+'%';};
};
for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    $('t'+i).className = 'show';
    cl('t'+i);
    for (var j=0; j<50; j++){
        cl('b'+i+'='+j+'%');
        setTimeout(makeHandler(i, j), 200);
    }
}
makeHandler = undefined;
```

If you can rely on ES5 features (because of the environment you're targeting, or because you've included an ES5 shim), you can get much the same effect using the new [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5). `Function#bind` creates a new function just like `makeHandler` does, but there's always the possibility the engine can optimize a bit:

```
function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    $('t'+i).className = 'show';
    cl('t'+i);
    for (var j=0; j<50; j++){
        cl('b'+i+'='+j+'%');
        setTimeout(handler.bind(undefined, i, j), 200);
    }
}
function handler(){
    $('b'+ivalue).style.width = jvalue+'%';
}
```

The first argument to `bind` is what `this` should be in the function; in our case we don't care, so I've specified `undefined` (which means the function will get `this` referencing the global object — `window`, on browsers — unless this is *strict mode* code, in which case `this` will actually be `undefined`).

#### They all run at the same time (200ms later)

All of your functions are being scheduled to run 200ms after the above code. And so they will. :-) If you want to space them out, you'll want to increase that 200ms for each call to `setTimeout`. We can just multiply by `i` and `j`:

```
setTimeout(makeHandler(i, j), (200 * i * j) + 200);
```

Now the first one will run after 200ms, the second one 200ms later, etc. The whole thing will take about a minute to complete. This assumes you want the first element to grow, then the next, then the next, as opposed to all six of them growing in parallel with each other.

Alternately, you might want to have each function call its successor. That's probably what I'd do. So rather than scheduling 300 function calls, just schedule one and when it happens, schedule the next:

```
function $(s) { return document.getElementById(s); }

// Our counters are here
var i = 0, j = 0;

// This handles the outer portion of the loop (mostly)
function outer() {
    $('t'+i).className = 'show';
    cl('t'+i);
    j = 0;
    // Schedule the first inner portion 200ms from now
    setTimeout(inner, 200);
}

// This handles the inner portion of the loop (mostly)
function inner() {
    // Do this bit
    $('b'+i).style.width = j+'%';
    ++j;
    if (j < 50) {
       // Continue the inner loop in 200ms
       setTimeout(inner, 200);
    }
    else {
       // Set up next outer loop
       j = 0;
       ++i;
       if (i < 6) {
           // Not done yet, keep going
           setTimeout(outer, 200);
       }
     }
}

// Kick it off
setTimeout(outer, 200);
```

In the above, I've also moved these lines:

```
$('t'+i).className = 'show';
cl('t'+i);
```

...into the delayed code, which I suspected was appropriate.

#### More to explore:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Or create an anonymous function?

Comment: Thanks so much for explaianing, I tried the sample code, but it's still not performing as expected and I am not seeing the width increasing by 1% every 200 ms and there appears to be no delays, it all executes at once !

Comment: @Derek: While that's *possible*, I never suggest it. It's hard to read, hard to maintain, easy to get wrong, and means that you're creating and throwing away 6 * 50 = 300 functions (the anonymous makers). Much better in my view to have *one* maker function you reuse.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the handler to be invoked at 200ms intervals, one after the other. In this example it is still creating the timeouts all at once.

Comment: @crankshaft: Ah, that's a *different* problem. You've scheduled all of the functions to run at the same time. I'll edit, you want to increase that `200ms` for each function.

Comment: @crankshaft: Now the answer addresses that problem as well.

Comment: @TJ, yes, the 200ms basically is setting the width of a <div> element used as a percentage bar, and it should grow from zero width to 50%.

Comment: I think I have not explained very well, I will go back and edit the original question

Comment: @crankshaft: I've made one final edit near the end. Have to go, but I think the above gives you the tools you need to solve the problem. Best,

Comment: @TJ, thanks, what happens now is that all of the 't' elements are shown immediately, then the bars slowly grow by 200ms. But what I am trying to achieve is that one 't' element is shown at a time, then the 'b' element width is set in 200ms intervals, then when it's at full width the next t element is shown and it's associated 'b' element grows in width etc.

Comment: @TJ - Brilliant, yes the last example does exactly what I was unsucsessful in doing, many thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're *not* closing over the `i` and `j`:

```
setTimeout(function(i, j) { 
    return function() {
        $('b'+i).style.width = j+'%';
    }
}(i, j), 200);
```

Comment: You need parens around the anonymous function.

Comment: I don't think you need parentheses around the anonymous function - in this context JS is expecting a function expression anyway, so the parens don't do anything.

Comment: @nnnnnn Hmm, you're right. Before I "corrected" I did a quick check, but I singled out the function which causes a syntax error .. within the `setTimeout` it's indeed not required ;-)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yea, but he's invoking the anonymous function inline, that then returns another function.

Comment: @Peter it works fine without the parentheses :) Crockford says that's only to make you feel more comfortable hehe

Comment: @Peter - that doesn't matter. If you include an immediately invoked anonymous function as a statement on its own JS treats it as a function declaration statement - which would be a syntax error without a function name so _then_ you need parens (or some other operator) to force its interpretation as a function expression rather than as a declaration. But as a parameter within a function call (or as the RHS of an assignment, or in other places where an expression is expected) you don't need the parens.

Comment: @Jack Oooh yes I see that does work. Hmmm, sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () { alert('Refreshing…'); }, 2000);
```

It means after two seconds (2000 ms), show alert